# How do I push a Git tag in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-remote, git-tag

Does anyone know how to push a created tag to the remote repository using Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since version 1.52 from *Novembre 2020* (now newest is *March 2023* version 1.77) you can *push* tags by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then write `Git: Push Tags` and by pressing enter, you will push your created tags to your remote.